# AJAX Control Toolkit 15.1 - ScriptUserControl was removed, what is its replacement?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, devexpress

ScriptUserControl, used as a base class in an MVP implementation that I'm working on, was removed by DevExpress from the toolkit.  ScriptControlBase remains, but that inherits WebControl which doesn't jive when UserControl must be inherited/extended.

Has anyone brought in the new toolkit with this problem?  How should I go about replacing ScriptUserControl?

Comment: Did you follow the [upgrade instructions](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Upgrade%20your%20project%20to%20AjaxControlToolkit%20v15.1)?

Comment: Of course.  There is nothing in the documentation that we have seen detailing the change that I have mentioned above.  Still currently searching a workaround.  It's a fundamental problem for us as we have an implementation in which our underlying controls all inherit from UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and had to maintain own AjaxControlToolkit version since rework would be too expensive.
Recently I convinced AjaxControlToolkit DevEx team to implement necessary changes and published missing AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptUserControl as a separate Nuget package. Try:
`PM> Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptUserControl`